# How to set opacity for GRASS layers using command line?

Tags: grass-gis, transparency-opacity, command-line

In the process of learning GRASS, I am finding that I can learn many of the command-line methods that I need for scripting tasks from using the wxGUI, as it conveniently shows most of the underlying commands that it runs. This has not turned out to be the case for [setting the opacity of layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73195/how-to-set-partial-transparency-for-grass-layer/73227?noredirect=1#73227). A little Googling turned up a module called [g.pnmcomp](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.pnmcomp.html), which may be responsible for controlling layer opacity. Unfortunately, that module appears not to be intended for end-users and I have not found documentation that is sufficient for me to make use of it; I'd need to know how to generate the PPM/PGM pairs that it stacks, at least.

There to not appear to be arguments for opacity in `d.rast` or `d.vect`, and I suspect that it's the png or tif driver that would actually be handling the opacity of layers. That's the background, but my question is quite simple. How can I set the opacity of layers in maps created via the command line?

Comment: I think the short answer to your question is that you can't set the opacity for 'd.vect' and 'd.rast' from the command-line. It seems only possible from the wxGUI.

Comment: The way around is `r.blend` and `r.composite`. See also the following related thread in the grass-user mailing list: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2013-October/069028.html

Answer (score 2):

I used already (Python) scripts that uses GRASS commands, namely *d.mon*, *d.vect* 
 and *d.rast*, to create programmatically maps which works straightforward.

But as user dmci already stated there seems to be no way to set the opacity for a layer.